# Sort by number of matches on queries based on m2m field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I hope the title is not misleading.

Anyway, I have two models, both have m2m relationships with a third model.

```
class Model1: keywords = m2m(Keyword)
class Model2: keywords = m2m(Keyword)
```

Given the keywords for a Model2 instance like this:

```
keywords2 = model2_instance.keywords.all()
```

I need to retrieve the Model1 instances which have at least a keyword that is in keywords2, something like:

```
Model1.objects.filter(keywords__in=keywords2)
```

**and sort them by the number of keywords that match (dont think its possible via 'in' field lookup). Question is, how do i do this?**

I'm thinking of just manually interating through each of Model1 instances, appending them to a dictionary of results for every match, but I need this to scale, for say tens of thousands of records. Here is how I imagined it would be like:

```
result = {}
keywords2_ids = model2.keywords.all().values_list('id',flat=True)
for model1 in Model1.objects.all():
    keywords_matched = model1.keywords.filter(id__in=keywords2_ids).count()
    objs = result.get(str(keywords_matched), [])
    result[str(keywords_matched)] = objs.append(obj)
```

**There must be an faster way to do this. Any ideas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just switch to raw SQL. What you have to do is to write a custom [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) for `Model1` to return the sorted set of ids of Model1 objects based on the keyword match counts. The SQL is simple as joining the two many to many tables(Django automatically creates a table to represent a many to many relationship) on keyword ids and then grouping on Model1 ids for `COUNT` sql function. Then using an `ORDER BY` clause on those counts will produce the sorted `Model1` id list you need. In MySQL,

```
SELECT appname_model1_keywords.model1_id, count(*) as match_count FROM appname_model1_keywords
JOIN appname_model2_keywords 
ON (appname_model1_keywords.keyword_id = appname_model2_keywords.keyword_id)
WHERE appname_model2_keywords.model2_id = model2_object_id
GROUP BY appname_model1_keywords.model1_id
ORDER BY match_count
```

Here `model2_object_id` is the `model2_instance` id. This will definitely be faster and more scalable.